# Analytics API Embed - property and view fields not populating

Tags: javascript, html, google-api, google-analytics-api

(I know that a similar question exists but it does not mention any solutions.)

Okay, so I am following this [tutorial](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/basic-dashboard/). But after authenticating, I get these 3 dropdowns:
[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IufS9.png). It is supposed to populate those dropdowns and show data accordingly.

I have **2 properties** in the account associated with the email, I authorised with. I get no errors.

I tried creating a new property (in case it detects that) and also using another email.

**The thing is it is not populating the dropdowns on the documentation site as well!** (one can log in and it will show the fields and results)

Code I am using:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}


{% block body %}

<script>
    (function(w,d,s,g,js,fs){
      g=w.gapi||(w.gapi={});g.analytics={q:[],ready:function(f){this.q.push(f);}};
      js=d.createElement(s);fs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      js.src='https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
      fs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fs);js.onload=function(){g.load('analytics');};
    }(window,document,'script'));
</script>

<div id="embed-api-auth-container"></div>
<div id="chart-container"></div>
<div id="view-selector-container"></div>

<script>

    gapi.analytics.ready(function() {
    
      /**
       * Authorize the user immediately if the user has already granted access.
       * If no access has been created, render an authorize button inside the
       * element with the ID "embed-api-auth-container".
       */
      gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
        container: 'embed-api-auth-container',
        clientid: 'CLIENT_ID'
      });
    
    
      /**
       * Create a new ViewSelector instance to be rendered inside of an
       * element with the id "view-selector-container".
       */
      var viewSelector = new gapi.analytics.ViewSelector({
        container: 'view-selector-container'
      });
    
      // Render the view selector to the page.
      viewSelector.execute();

    
    
      /**
       * Create a new DataChart instance with the given query parameters
       * and Google chart options. It will be rendered inside an element
       * with the id "chart-container".
       */
      var dataChart = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
        query: {
          metrics: 'ga:sessions',
          dimensions: 'ga:date',
          'start-date': '30daysAgo',
          'end-date': 'yesterday'
        },
        chart: {
          container: 'chart-container',
          type: 'LINE',
          options: {
            width: '100%'
          }
        }
      });
    
    
      /**
       * Render the dataChart on the page whenever a new view is selected.
       */
      viewSelector.on('change', function(ids) {
        dataChart.set({query: {ids: ids}}).execute();
      });
    
    });
</script>

{% endblock body %}
```

*CLIENT_ID was replaced with actual client id

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You may want to look more into the official documentation from google: https://developers.google.com/analytics

Comment: Yeah, I looked into this doc https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/web-js and found out it requires view id, but in Analytics 4 (Web+App) they have removed views (or at least that's what a few articles said). Do you have any idea on how to get that fixed?

Comment: Thanks, figured it out :)

Answer (score 0):

The google analytics embeded api is a JavaScript library which was originally designed to work with Google analytics core reporting api v3.

It was never upgraded to work with the Google analytics reporting api v4 which has a large number of dimensions and metrics that are available in the Google analytics core reporting api v3.

It has not it been upgraded to work with the Google analytics data api for use with GA4 accounts.

I guess what i am saying is that you are trying to use a very old library which has not been updated to work with the newer systems.

Comment: Oh, is there anything that can work with Analytics v4?

Comment: Thanks! I just figured it out! It might not be the best way, but as long as the client doesn't care, I don't care :)

Answer (score 0):

On your analytics dashboard

1. Create a new property
2. While in the first part of creation, click 'advanced'
3. Turn on the Universal Property option
4. Proceed as you want
5. You will get the option to create views in that property.

[Refer to this if you don't understand the above steps](https://www.analyticsmania.com/other-posts/how-to-create-a-universal-analytics-property/)

Thanks